# Visual Studio Code incorrectly complains about not finding module

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

Since upgrading from Vue 2.0 to Vue 2.5, Visual Studio Code complains about not finding a module. But when compiling with Webpack, the module IS found and compiled! Also, modules ARE found from .vue files, just not from index.ts

index.ts

```
import App from './components/app.vue'  // VS Code can't find module
                                           but webpack still compiles it
```

app.vue

```
import Card from "./card.vue"  // VS Code does find module
```

My directory structure

```
src
-index.ts
-components
---app.vue
---card.vue
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es2015",
        "lib": ["dom","es5","es2015.promise"]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which Vue.js plugin do you use?

Comment: Vetur with VS Code